# Can't connect to a machine via Cisco VPN on Mac

Tags: mac, cisco-vpn-client

I have a curious problem. I can connect to work's VPN using the Cisco VPN Client. I can get to tge Internet through that VPN. When I go check the IP online it tells me the IP address of the server I connected to. However, when I try to ping one of the machines at work I get nothing. And traceroute says there is no route to the destination. But it works for Google.

What is the reason? Is some traffic not sent through the VPN on Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured this out in the end. The problem was that home router had the same IP address as the one at work. So the packets were not sent correctly. So the easiest thing was to change default home router IP address. This instantly fixed the problem. I guess flushing IP tables manually might have also worked.

Answer (score 0):

It´s very likely with a Cisco IPSec setup that the servers Firewall (ASA) is set up not to answer on incoming ICMP-Packets. See also here:
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_tech_note09186a0080094e8a.shtml